# How can i dispatch something with react+redux+router from nav item without render anything?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, react-redux

My application has a map with a nav. The first two options open a modal window for configuration. For the third item, a want to execute a server process and update the map with the result, which is already rendered. How can I archive this?

Screen:

[image]

Routes:

```
class ModalSwitch extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.previousLocation = "/"
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
        const { location } = this.props
        if (
            nextProps.history.action !== 'POP' &&
            (!location.state || !location.state.modal)
        ) {
            this.previousLocation = this.props.location
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { location } = this.props
        const isModal = !!(
            location.state &&
            location.state.modal &&
            this.previousLocation !== location
        )

        return (
            <div>
                <Switch location={isModal ? this.previousLocation : location}>
                    <Route path='/' component={Home} />
                    <Route path='/modal1/' component={Modal1} />
                    <Route path='/modal2/' component={Modal2} />                        
                </Switch>
                {isModal ? <Route path='/modal1/' component={Modal1} /> : null}
                {isModal ? <Route path='/modal2/' component={Modal2} /> : null}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const Routes = () => (
    <Router>
        <Route component={ModalSwitch} />
    </Router>
)

export default Routes
```

Menu (rendered by Home):

```
export default class Menu extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <Link
                    key={0}
                    to={{
                        pathname: "/modal1",
                        state: { modal: true }
                    }}>
                    <p>Item 1</p>
                </Link>
                <Link
                    key={1}
                    to={{
                        pathname: "/modal2",
                        state: { modal: true }
                    }}>
                    <p>Item 2</p>
                </Link>                                
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Should I put a new Link to call a server process? If so, what I need to pass to pathname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your "link" be a dead link that calls a function

```
<a href="javascript:;" onClick={this.handleClick}>Process</a>
```

keep it an anchor tag so it will be styled the same as the React-Router's `Link`

then your handleClick function would look like this

```
handleClick = () => {
    if (someValToMakeApiCall) {
        this.props.myProcessAction(someData)
    }
}
```